# In a known finite episodic task, is there still value to discount?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, discount-factor

Sutton and Barto explains that in an continuing task, $\gamma$ is used to make the reward not infinite.  **In a known finite episodic task, does $\gamma$ retain any value?**  It is said that changing $\gamma$ changes how near-sighted an agent is but that seems more like hyperparameterization to suit a given task, not a specific strength.

For example:

If we consider a multi-arm bandit with two states, a $\gamma$ of zero is fine because one only needs to maximize the present decision.  If the agent was only given 10000 pulls, a $\gamma$ of 1 might be noisier but the actions in a state should approach their actual values on a long enough timeline.

Comment: Yes. The use of discount factor helps reduce the variance when computing the multi-step return. Future rewards which are more uncertain receive a higher discount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall reasoning sounds reasonable. In a known finite episodic task, while the choice of $\gamma$ could be seen as a global hyperparameter as you narrated, the impact of $\gamma$ is more localized within each episode and its choice is to influence the agent's exploration-exploitation tradeoff based on the characteristics of its specific task and the environment. There is no one-size-fits-all value for $\gamma$. For instance, a short-term swing trader's $\gamma$ must be smaller than a long term investor's, on the other hand a hyperparameter of a model is generally systematically tuned by some grid search like method to achieve possibly best training and test performance without such prior insight.